# Magento Controller displaying big XML file causes odd rendering in Browser

Tags: php, xml, magento, google-chrome, magento-1.7

I am working on a relatively extensive but not huge XML file that is being delivered from a custom Module in Magento using a controller. Everything has been going well and I have been able to get it to work and add nodes with no issues. The browser (Chrome in this case) has been rendering the XML document fine and stylizing it as expected. In order to display the XML headers properly via Magento I am using the following code:

```
/* Set display to render output as an XML document */
$this->loadLayout(false);
$this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-Type','text/xml');
echo "<Magento >";
.
.
.
echo "</Magento>\n";
$this->renderLayout();
```

When the output reaches 140 nodes, it stops rendering as formatted XML and just shows the data as if it is being rendered as HTML and doesn't know the node definition. Example:

[image: rendered incorrectly]

If I comment a node out so there are 139 it will render properly. If I save the full 140+ node XML page as a file then drop that file into Chrome, it renders properly. For Example:

[image: rendered correctly]

If I run the 140+ node XML file through a validator it comes through as valid XML code. I also get the same result of a broken rendering display if I use Firefox instead to view the page.

The question. Is there a limit as to how big an XML file can be to have it be delivered via a Magento Controller? If so, can I reset this limit to more than 139 nodes so this renders properly? Conversely, should I not worry about if the browser is rendering the page properly because it is going to be used by a different program and not a browser?

Comment: If I would need to guess quickly, I'd say this is chrome, not the XML.

Comment: That is what I thought too but it does the same thing in Firefox.

Comment: Why do you do that: `$this->renderLayout();`? Didn't you already deactivate the layout?

Comment: The example page I pulled the code from had it so I left it in. If I comment it out there is no change. Is using 'echo' to send this to the browser the right way to handle it or should I be doing this some other way?

Comment: You're not setting your header correctly. (My initial answer was off base, updated below)

Comment: @GregDemetrick Thanks.. In my problem, header is not set for small array data so we use this $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-Type','text/xml'); to set header and now it completely work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your header with `curl`.  My guess it it's not being set.

```
curl -I http://example.com
```

Try setting your header directly with

```
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
```

Setting a header on the response object will only impact content that's delivered via the response object.  Since you're `echo`ing code directly, the response object never gets the chance to send its headers.

Both Chrome and Firefox have a set of heuristics that attempt to guess how a document should be rendered.  Even with a `text/html` header a short XML document may be detected as XML, triggering XML rendering.  Once it reachers a certain length, the browsers guess that's it's an HTML document, and the HTML rendering engine takes over.

Ensuring your header is set correctly should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this problem happens when you break a tag (not close it) or insert characters not supported. Unknown size limitations of XML, perhaps your browser validation is crashing.

Comment: Please see in the question that if I output the page to a file and drop it back into the browser it will render properly. The only thing that is different is delivery from a server vs dropping a file. The XML is not broken or has invalid characters in it. Otherwise the loading of the file should give me the same broken results.